# Error running a Gazebo simulation inside Docker container

Tags: docker, opengl, nvidia-docker, ros2, gazebo-simu

I'm working on a project for university. We have to containerize a Gazebo simulation using Docker.

While researching on how to do this I came across this link, and tried running the simulation shown in it. If it works I think we can just change some stuff and make it work for our project. This is the link detailing the simulation I'm trying to run:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/robomaker/latest/dg/run-hello-world-ros-2.html

All the code needed to reproduce what we have tried to do is found in that Amazon AWS guide so I won't paste it in here for the most part.

Some info on the system and the technologies we're working with:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa
- Gazebo 11
- ROS2 Foxy
- NVIDIA GeForce rtx 2070 with version 510 drivers

The simulation is split in 3 images, Base, RobotApp and SimulationApp. We then run the 2 app images. When using the command "docker run" given in the example the first one creates a spinning object and seems to work just fine.

Docker command for the first one:

```
docker run -it -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/ --name robot_app \
-u robomaker -e ROBOMAKER_GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:5555 \
-e ROBOMAKER_ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 \
helloworldsampleappros2foxygazebo11robotapp:latest
```

Docker command for the second one:

```
docker run -it -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/ --name sim_app \
-u robomaker -e ROBOMAKER_GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:5555 \
-e ROBOMAKER_ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 \
helloworldsampleappros2foxygazebo11simapp:latest
```

The second one gives me this error message along some warnings:

```
[gzserver-1] libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
[gzserver-1] libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Here's all the messages printed to console when running the second Docker command:

```
ROS_VERSION=2
NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
HOSTNAME=0ff33fe3f61a
ROBOMAKER_GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:5555
PWD=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws
NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=graphics, display
ROBOMAKER_ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
HOME=/home/robomaker
GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins:
LANG=C.UTF-8
GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://models.gazebosim.org
AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh:/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/hello_world_simulation:/opt/ros/foxy
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh:/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/hello_world_simulation
GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-11:
COLCON_PREFIX_PATH=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages
TERM=xterm
DISPLAY=:1
SHLVL=1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins:/opt/ros/foxy/opt/yaml_cpp_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/foxy/opt/rviz_ogre_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/foxy/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/foxy/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins:
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-11/models:
PATH=/opt/ros/foxy/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ROS_DISTRO=foxy
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0
OLDPWD=/
_=/usr/bin/printenv
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/robomaker/.ros/log/2022-02-04-12-17-26-791225-0ff33fe3f61a-39
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh/share/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh/launch/spawn_turtlebot.launch.py:61: UserWarning: The parameter 'node_executable' is deprecated, use 'executable' instead
  Node(
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [41]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-2]: process started with pid [43]
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1643977047.395921509] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1643977047.396308383] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh/share/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle_pi.urdf
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1643977047.398652203] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1643977047.399013641] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity

[gzserver-1] libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
[gzserver-1] libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1643977047.904187249] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1643977048.247457510] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=imu'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=imu' instead.
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.250959996] [turtlebot3_imu]: <initial_orientation_as_reference> is unset, using default value of false to comply with REP 145 (world as orientation reference)
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1643977048.251600689] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=imu'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=imu' instead.
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1643977048.335266898] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [robot]
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1643977048.341230833] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1643977048.344790289] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 43]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.476454488] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 separation set to [0.287000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.476502091] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 diameter set to [0.066000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.477502575] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Subscribed to [/cmd_vel]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.478593142] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Advertise odometry on [/odom]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.479685530] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Publishing odom transforms between [odom] and [base_footprint]
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1643977048.487264720] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=joint_states'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=joint_states' instead.
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.490953326] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_left_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1643977048.490991604] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_right_joint]
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1643977048.491042853] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=joint_states'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=joint_states' instead.
```

After this I follow the last set of instructions:

```
# Enable access to X server to launch Gazebo from docker container
$ xhost +

# Check that the robot_app and sim_app containers are running. The command should list both containers
$ docker container ls

# Connect to the sim app container
$ docker exec -it sim_app bash

# Launch Gazebo from within the container
$ /home/robomaker/simulation-entrypoint.sh ros2 launch gazebo_ros gzclient.launch.py
```

And get the following error:

```
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[gzclient   -1] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[ERROR] [gzclient   -1]: process has died [pid 156, exit code 139, cmd 'gzclient   '].
```

Here's all the messages printed to console when running the commands above:

```
ROS_VERSION=2
NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
HOSTNAME=0ff33fe3f61a
ROBOMAKER_GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:5555
PWD=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws
NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=graphics, display
ROBOMAKER_ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
HOME=/home/robomaker
GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins:
LANG=C.UTF-8
GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://models.gazebosim.org
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh:/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/hello_world_simulation:/opt/ros/foxy
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/turtlebot3_description_reduced_mesh:/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install/hello_world_simulation
GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-11:
COLCON_PREFIX_PATH=/home/robomaker/workspace/aws-robomaker-sample-application-helloworld-ros2/simulation_ws/install
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages
TERM=xterm
DISPLAY=:1
SHLVL=2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins:/opt/ros/foxy/opt/yaml_cpp_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/foxy/opt/rviz_ogre_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/foxy/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/foxy/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins:
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-11/models:
PATH=/opt/ros/foxy/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ROS_DISTRO=foxy
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0
OLDPWD=/
_=/usr/bin/printenv
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/robomaker/.ros/log/2022-02-04-12-17-58-244883-0ff33fe3f61a-124
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzclient   -1]: process started with pid [156]
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
[gzclient   -1] libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[gzclient   -1] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[ERROR] [gzclient   -1]: process has died [pid 156, exit code 139, cmd 'gzclient   '].
```

That said we checked every post for hours to try to fix this:

```
[gzserver-1] libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
[gzserver-1] libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

but it still does not work. We tried reinstalling NVIDIA drivers, found a bunch of posts about some Mesa drivers that give this error, but i checked and i don't have Mesa under my driver files.
This is the forum: https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t

And this is what i get after running `sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so` :

```
libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libcogl.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
    libQt5OpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
```

We also tought maybe we're missing openGL or something similar inside the Dockerfile so we tried to get Hardware acceleration to work, following instructions here:
http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration
and so we have tried installing nvidia-docker2.

If we run `nvidia-docker version` we get:

```
NVIDIA Docker: 2.8.0
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12
 Git commit:        e91ed57
 Built:             Mon Dec 13 11:45:33 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.12
  Git commit:       459d0df
  Built:            Mon Dec 13 11:43:42 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

We followed the instructions provided here: https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/user-guide.html to set the environmental variables we need to control which libraries will be mounted in the container.

Since our error seems to indicate that OpenGL is missing I added

```
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES graphics, display
```

to the first Dockerfile. `graphics` is required for openGL and `display` for x11 display (which I think we use since something about it is written in the original Dockerfile, but I'm not sure about it).

After all this and some more, we still get those errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is too late for your university project, but what I found to work is to [use NVIDIA's official graphics image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53823600/13483164)

Comment: It'll be better to post the code you used here.

Comment: @cconsta1 Not possible due to corporate policy. You can copy it from that link instead :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20789288/4086194) worked for me.

```bash
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
gazebo
```

or

```bash
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 gazebo
```